# How to reload stripe elements according to different API keys?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have multiple accounts of stripe for multiple countries, I want to call stripe load promise onchange of country with different API public key.

So If I select **UK** from dropdown than stripe elements should be for **UK** and if I change it to **US** than stripe elements should be for **US**. But in my case when I call for **UK country** than it's working and if I it call **US** after **UK** than it's never update stripe elements for **US**.
And in network console it alwayse showing UK elements even I have selected US country.

My Public keys are loading according to country wise change and promise of loadstripe is also generated according to public keys of coutnry wise change, but the iframe of stripe elements never change.

```
        if(nextProps.payment_methods){
            nextProps.payment_methods.map(val => {
                if(val.name==="stripe" && val.public_key){
                    return_stripe_promise = loadStripe(val.public_key)
                }
            })
            this.setState({
                loadstripe_promise : return_stripe_promise
            })
        }

        <Elements stripe={this.state.loadstripe_promise}>
             <CheckoutForm ref={this.child} />
        </Elements>
```

Now my question is that, how to reload iframe/elements of stripe according to latest stripeload promise? Any idea please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After beating my head against the wall on this for hours, I finally get the answer.

Simply just pass the key attribute with a unique id in the Elements component of the stripe and it will re render everytime according to latest stripe public key.

```
<Elements key={unique_key_number} stripe={this.state.loadstripe_promise}>
   <CheckoutForm ref={this.child} />
</Elements>
```

Comment: surprisingly this was the solution to my problem. I was actually passing two different client secrets so as to render an updated Payment Element. One that had `setup_future_usage` and the other was `null`. Trick was to allow the user to use a checkbox to decide if they wanted to store their payment method. Had to create 2 payment intents (did not find a simple way via stripe) and then re-render the element and test. All i did is set each with a unique key, e.g. `<Elements key={2}...`. Thanks for posting this solution.